# SQL querying - Doctors and Hospitals

Tags: sql

1. Display doctorid, dname, total fees received by the doctor(s) who have treated more than one patient?
2. Display hospitalid, hname, htype of hospital(s) which has the highest number of doctors associated with them.

Tables

#### table 1 - patient

```
patientid
pname
address
amount
ptype
```

#### table 2 - hospital

```
hospitalid
hname
htype
```

#### table 3 - doctor

```
doctorid
dname
specialization
hospitalid
status
```

#### table 4 - billing

```
billingid
patientid
doctorid
fees
billdate
```

---

So far this is what I have:

select 
    billing.doctorid, 
    sum (fees) as totalfees, 
    doctor.dname
from 
    billing, doctor
where
     doctor.doctorid = billing.doctorid
group by
    billing.doctorid, 
    doctor.dname
having 
    min ( billing.patientid ) <> max ( billing.patientid )

Comment: Looks like homework.... What did you try?

Comment: If you have problems with your homework, then show what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: OK. Go ahead. Display those for us. We'll wait. No hurry.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  Whether it is homework or not, please show what you've tried, and where you're getting stuck.  People will help you if you show you've tried, but they are reluctant to just write code to solve your problems when you've not shown that you've tried anything.  Also, for DBMS questions, it often helps to specify which DBMS you are using.  Although the queries can be answered in standard SQL, there are issues like 'does your DBMS support the OLAP functions' (though you probably haven't been taught those yet anyway).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately, your question does not show any effort, it is just a "do-it-for-me" question, and that does not fit this site. I suggest you read this article: http://whathaveyoutried.com It will help you understand why it is important to show some effort if you want to get help.

Comment: I tried many didn't work.

Comment: @ShanthaPrasath Show us what have you tried. Post your code and a sample of your expected result. **We can help you**, but we need a place to start

Comment: select h.hospitalid,hname, htype from hospital h where h.hospitalid in (select d.hospitalid from doctor d where d.doctorid in(select max(doctorid) from doctor);

Comment: I'm sorry people i'm new to this..
I've been trying this out for 3 hrs almost not able to find any answer.

Comment: @ShanthaPrasath Thank you for posting your query. Now we can start to help you

Comment: Which Relation Database Management System (ie SQL Server, Oracle, etc) are you writing this for?

Comment: Not able to solve the next one: please help From keyword missing error: select * from hospital where hospitalid = (select hospitalid from doctor group by hospitalid having count ( doctorid ) = (select max ( doctoramt ) from (select count doctorid) as doctoramt from doctor group by hospitalid) as tbltemp));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll help you with your first question, and I'll leave to you the second.

> 1. Display doctorid, dname, total fees received by the doctor(s) who have treated more than one patient?

Let's split this problem in pieces:

So you need first to know which doctors have treated more than one patient. That information is in the table `billing`. So:

```
select doctorId, count(patientId) as patientCount
from (select distinct doctorId, patientId from billing) as a
group by doctorId
having count(patientId)>1;
```

This query will return only the Ids of the doctors that have more than one patient. Notice that I'm using a subquery to deduplicate the doctor-patient tuple.

Now let's attack the other part of this question: The total fees of each doctor. Again, that info is in the table `billing`:

```
select doctorId, sum(fees) as totalFees
from billing
group by doctorId;
```

Finally, let's put it all together, and include the doctor's info, which is in the table `doctor`:

```
select
    d.doctorId, d.doctorName, a.totalFees
from
    doctor as d
    inner join (
        select doctorId, sum(fees) as totalFees
        from billing
        group by doctorId
    ) as a on d.doctorId = a.doctorId
    inner join (
        select doctorId, count(patientId) as patientCount
        from (select distinct doctorId, patientId from billing) as a
        group by doctorId
        having count(patientId)>1;
    ) as b on d.doctorId = b.doctorId;
```

Hope this helps

---

Things you need to study and (or) keep in mind:

1. You need to understand how to relate data stored in different tables. Study how to use `INNER JOIN` (and also `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`)
2. You need to understand how does `GROUP BY` works, and how to use aggregate functions (`sum()`, `count()`, etcetera).
3. You know how to write subqueries. Now try to use them not only for `where` conditions, but as data sources (including them in `from` statements)
4. Keep a copy of the reference manual of your RDBMS at hand. Also a good book on SQL can help you (go to a bookstore or library and find one you like).

Comment: Found an easier answer 
select 
 billing.doctorid, 
 sum (fees) as totalfees, 
 doctor.dname
from 
 billing, doctor
where
  doctor.doctorid = billing.doctorid
group by
 billing.doctorid, 
 doctor.dname
having 
 min ( billing.patientid ) <> max ( billing.patientid )

Comment: What is a good book for SQL ...
I need one really badly

Comment: Tell me a good book for sql

Comment: @ShanthaPrasath Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Oracle, Access)? For MySQL, the online reference manual can cover your back. If you need learning resources, use Google: find online tutorials and use them

Comment: Not able to solve the next one: please help
From keyword missing error:
select * from hospital where hospitalid = (select hospitalid from doctor group by hospitalid having count ( doctorid ) = (select max ( doctoramt ) from (select count doctorid) as doctoramt from doctor group by hospitalid) as tbltemp));

Comment: @ShanthaPrasath You need to split the problem in pieces: Divide and conquer. First, count the doctors per hospital (the data is in the table `doctor`), then join the data with the table `hospital`. Remember: `count()` is an aggregate function (you need to include a `group by` specification in your query). That stuff you are writing (`select count doctorid`) is not correct; it should be `select hospitalid, count(doctorid) as countOfDoctors from doctor group by hospitalid`. You really need to study!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already got your answer, but since I wrote it up...

```
Select  d.doctorID, 
        d.dName, 
        Sum(b.fees) [total fees received]
From    doctor d
Join    billing b
        On  d.doctorID = b.doctorID
Group   By  d.doctorID, 
            d.dName
Having  Count(Distinct patientID) > 1

With    CTE As
(
        Select  Rank() Over (Order By Count(d.doctorID) Desc) As priCount, 
                h.hospitalID, 
                h.hName, 
                h.hType, 
                Count(d.doctorID) As doctors
        From    hospital h
        Join    doctor d
                On  h.hospitalID = d.hospitalID
        Group   By  h.hospitalID,
                    h.hName,
                    h.hType
)
Select  hosptitalID,
        hName,
        hType
From    CTE
Where   priCount = 1
```